# How do I add a 0 in front of a string of numbers for all cells?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, format, conditional-formatting

I need to add a 0 before all cells in the A column on Google Sheets. Is there a code or formatting function I can add in? I need them to look like A2. A3 is what I have right now. There are a total of 783 that were extracted like this and I don't wanna do this manually

[image: Reference image]

I tried formatting a few ways but I'm still a beginner in Sheets & Excel

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ARRAYFORMULA in another column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(0&A1:A)

=INDEX(0&A1:A)
```

(PS: you may change A1:A with A1:A783)

---

If you want to just change the values in that column, you may use FIND AND REPLACE --> (Edit -> Find and Replace), be sure you tick *"Search using regular expressions"*. Put to find `^` and to replace `0`

[image]

---

NOTE: thanks to @rockinfreakshow, prior this second option, first format to plain text:

[image]

And then do the replacement:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in the adjacent cell:

[image]

Then you apply it across all your rows.

Do not forget to copy and paste as values.